# User Inserted Rows/Columns Impacting Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to determine how I can have a user insert columns and/or rows without it impacting the rest of the code in the macro.

Defining names for my objects and using r1c1 references in VBA does not seem to help as these inserted columns shift those references and names as well.

Am I missing something that should be completely obvious???
Or is what I am trying to accomplish not possible?

**UPDATE:** When I name a range in excel (without VBA) everything seems to work fine with inserted columns. However, when I name the range with VBA everything messes up. Here is a sample of some code to work with.

When this below code is run... I am not able to insert columns as my MSGBOX's don't realize the named cell has shifted to the right. HOWEVER, if I were to remove the first line in this code and just name the cell "GanttStartLocation" which is quoted out in the code... this seems to work fine.

WHY DOES THiS NOT WORK WHEN NAMED WITH VBA????

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="DEFINENAMETEST", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R10C14"


Dim rGanttLocation As Range 'Range used to define where the Gantt chart begins
Dim iFirstRowGantt As Integer 'Defines the first row of the Gantt chart based on rGanttLocation
Dim iFirstColumnGantt As Integer 'Defines the first column of the Gantt chart based on rGanttLocation

'Set rGanttLocation = Worksheets(1).Range("GanttStartLocation")
Set rGanttLocation = Worksheets(1).Range("DEFINENAMETEST")
iFirstRowGantt = rGanttLocation.Row
iFirstColumnGantt = rGanttLocation.Column

MsgBox (iFirstRowGantt)
MsgBox (iFirstColumnGantt)
```

Comment: It's difficult to make useful suggestions here without knowing exactly what your code is doing

Comment: Have you tried using [Tables](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)? They make life easier, and you can reefrence the columns (fields) easily like this: `TableName[FieldName]`. Also, inserting columns won't expand or change your named references.

Answer (score 0):

Use a named range for your cells so that addition of rows/columns are less likely to impact your code if rows/columns are added inside the range. For example: if `D1-F10` was called `testrange`, executing the following subroutine will give red background color to the range

```
Public Sub Test()
    Range("testrange").Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

If a new row and column are added to this range, and the subroutine is re-executed after replacing vbRed with vbYellow, the entire range (with new column and row) will turn yellow.

Outside of the named range, it's going to take decent amount of work to keep your Macro's generic, from what I understand.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I'm going to see if I could perhaps allow the insert but to dissuade it through altering the colors.

Comment: Does this answer help you put closure to your question?

Comment: Although I appreciate the response; I don't believe it actually answers the question

Comment: I'm sorry the answer didn't help. Would you like assistance on your code under updated section?

Comment: If there is something that is obvious that would be great but I really don't want to trouble you if it's not!